# ID int limit in POST method

Tags: php, twitter

I'm using this library https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php to use the Twitter API.

I'm using a .csv to pass Tweet IDs, using GET (showids.php) just works fine:

```
    <?php
    require('TwitterAPIExchange.php');
    require("auth.php");
    $fichero=fopen("tweets.csv","r");
    while(!feof($fichero)){
        $linea=fgets($fichero);
        $id=(substr($linea,1,18));
        echo ($id."<br />");
        $url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/show.json";
        $requestMethod = "GET";
        $getfield = '?id='.$id;
        $twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
        $response = $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
            ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
        ->performRequest();
    print_r($response);
    echo("<br />");
}
fclose($fichero);
```

but when I use a POST method (delids.php) it cuts the Tweet ID at int limit.

```
<?php
require('TwitterAPIExchange.php');
require("auth.php");
$fichero=fopen("tweets.csv","r");
while(!feof($fichero)){
    $linea=fgets($fichero);
        $tid=substr($linea,1,18);
    echo ($tid."<br />");
    $url = sprintf('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/destroy/%d.json',$tid);
    echo ($url."<br />");
    $method = 'POST';
    $params = array(
    'id'=>$tid,
    );
    $twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
    echo $twitter->buildOauth($url,$method)
        ->setPostfields($params)
        ->performRequest();
    echo("<br />");
}
fclose($fichero);
```

IMG with the error: [int limit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvt3x.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use sprintf, instead just add the id inbetween by concatenating the string:

```
$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/destroy/'.$tid.'.json');
```

that should work i think.

Some explanation can be found here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php
the d accepts an integer which is why it cuts it off at the max integer value.

> d - the argument is treated as an integer, and presented as a (signed)
>   decimal number.

Comment: Yes! That's it! Thanks! :D (I really don't know how the f** i didn't see that...)

Comment: haha, happens to the best of us ^^ A fresh pair of eyes helps sometimes. I've been in your situation way too many times :D